# Give an example of gauge choice for magnetic vector potential that is periodic

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, potential

How do I construct a periodic vector potential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Periodic potentials necessarily imply periodic fields, so this would restrict the physical situations your field would be applicable to.

That said, **any** set of potentials will give some physically viable set of electric and magnetic fields (though the charges and currents might be difficult to arrange, and the fields may or may not have finite energy). You are therefore free to postulate any periodic function you want.